# jQuery Animate - navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, jquery-animate

I am using the jQuery function .animate to highlight navigation links one by one. They are in a ul. I can get this to work, just wondering if there is a way to shorten my code so that I don't have to highlight each item individually. Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
    });
    $('#button1').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
    });
    $('#button2').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
    });
    $('#button2').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
    });
    $('#button3').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
    });
    $('#button3').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
    });
    $('#button4').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
    });
    $('#button4').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine all your selectors into one statement, then attach the event listeners:

```
$('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color:"#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color:"#FF9B05",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe define two functions :

```
function animateLeave() {
     $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
}

 function animateEnter() {
     $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
}
```

Assign the following classes to the appropriate buttons (i.e., `button1` will have `class="leaveAnimation"`), and do :

```
$('.leaveAnimation').mouseleave(animateLeave);
```

Same for enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^=button]').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FFFFFF",
            backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
        });
    });
$('[id^=button]').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color:"#FF9B05",
            backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
        });
    });
```

This "^" will search for element id starts with "button"

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify your buttons with a common class rather than with the id.

for example by assigning the class "buttons", and the javascript code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".buttons").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color:"#FFFFFF",
        backgroundColor: "#FF9B05"
    });
});
$(".buttons").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        color:"#FF9B05",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
    });
});
```